# check if number is between row of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Want to check if value is between the row of array.
here the value  347 is in between the 1st row of aa but not second , so how to check for it ?

```
aa= np.array([[348 ,345],
              [460 , 459 ]])

value = 347

print(value> aa[:,0]) ==  (value < aa[:,1]) ## help here
```

answer must be

```
[True False]
```

Comment: So? Do you have a question? [ask]

Comment: i am trying to check between 348 and 345 not between 348 and 460  . row wise not column wise

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `!=` or `^` to get `[True False]`.

*But your question is asking for something completely different from the answer you are trying to get.*

First, note that `aa[:,0]` is `[348, 460]` and `a[:,1]` is `[345, 459]`. So to have anything `True`, I think you to use `a[0,:]` and `a[1,:]` (note transposition of `:` with `0` or `1` -- order matters).

Now with this transposition we have that `value > aa[0,:]` is `[False, True]` *and not* `[True, False]` and `value < aa[:,1]` is `[True True]`. Your first answer should be `False` since `347` is *not* between `348` and `460` and your second should be `True`.

So to put it all together:

```
((value > aa[0,:])) == (value < aa[1,:])
#array([False,  True])
```

**UPDATE based on your comment to your question above**

I just saw your comment and I think I misunderstood what you are trying to do. Sorry I had misunderstood, but it speaks also to the importance of clearly explaining what you are trying to do in your quesiton.

If I now understand correctly, the problem is that the numbers in your row are not necessarily in the right order, so you need to check for `min` and `max` values. You can use the `axis` keyword in [`np.amin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html)and [`np.amax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html), which you can call as `np.amin(aa, axis = 1)` or [`aa.min(axis = 1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) (same for [`max`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)). So your answer could look something like:

```
(value > aa.min(axis = 1)) == (value < aa.max(axis = 1))
#array([ True, False])
```