# check if value is between two values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

how to check if given number is in between two numbers row wise . for e.g - 101 from b is in 100 and 200  of a i.e 0 index of a .

```
a = np.array([
     [100, 200],# 101 between 100 and 200
     [150, 160] # 156 between 150 and 160

             ])

b = np.array([

          [101], [156] , [300]

            ])
```

answer must be

```
for 101 - True , false 
for 156 - false, true
for 300 - false , false
```

Comment: Post your code, also maybe google for an answer before posting this kinda of low quality question? And maybe just compare the number if its greater than the lower limit and lower than the higher limit????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if number is between row of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371682/check-if-number-is-between-row-of-numpy-array)

Comment: Please don't repost your question. Your own duplicate already has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether particular number (*n*) is in the range between borders defined by each row
in a 2-column table (*tbl*), define the following function:

```
def isInRange(n, tbl):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: row[0] <= n <= row[1], 1, tbl)\
        .tolist()
```

Then, to get the result for all elements in *b*, run the following
list comprehension:

```
result = [isInRange(x, a) for x in np.nditer(b)]
```

The result, for your data sample, is:

```
[[True, False], [True, True], [False, False]]
```

Note that the result for *156* is *[True, True]* (different to what
you wrote), because *156* is within both ranges defined by rows of *a*
table.

Comment: I timed your solution and some alternatives.  `nditer` and `apply_along_axis` don't help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `nditer` does not help with times:

```
In [42]: result = [isInRange(x, a) for x in np.nditer(b)]
In [43]: result
Out[43]: [[True, False], [True, True], [False, False]]
In [44]: timeit result = [isInRange(x, a) for x in np.nditer(b)]
262 µs ± 9.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Iterating on `b` directly, or on the `ravel` to get rid of the inner dimension:

```
In [45]: result = [isInRange(x, a) for x in b.ravel()]
In [46]: result
Out[46]: [[True, False], [True, True], [False, False]]
In [47]: timeit result = [isInRange(x, a) for x in b.ravel()]
230 µs ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

The use of `apply_along_axis` also does not help, especially in the case of a 1d array.  An equivalent list comprehension:

```
def foo(n, tbl):
    return [row[0] <= n <= row[1] for row in tbl]
```

Is much faster:

```
In [50]: result = [foo(x, a) for x in np.nditer(b)]
In [51]: result
Out[51]: [[True, False], [True, True], [False, False]]

In [53]: timeit result = [foo(x, a) for x in np.nditer(b)]
41.7 µs ± 1.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [54]: timeit result = [foo(x, a) for x in b.ravel()]
12.2 µs ± 99.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

But we don't have to do any (python level) iteration:

```
In [59]: ((a[:, 0] <= b) & (b <= a[:, 1])).tolist()
Out[59]: [[True, False], [True, True], [False, False]]
In [60]: timeit((a[:, 0] <= b) & (b <= a[:, 1])).tolist()
12.3 µs ± 3.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

For this small example the pure list code is just as fast, but the array approach will scale better.